# Calculate hour difference between given date and current date in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to check to see how many hours difference there are between a given date and the current date. I'm looking for a date that's less then 24 hours away!

I thought this would work but it's giving me a true statement when the EventDateTime is Sunday which is greater then 24 hours out!

```
bool lessThen24Hours = (spaceEvent.EventDateTime - DateTime.Now).Hours < 24 ? true : false;
```

Comment: 1. `? true : false` is redundant and can be removed. 2. try printing/inspecting the intermediate results of your calculation. Is `EventDateTime` actually what you expect at time of execution? What is the `Hours` value that comes out? 3. It's "than", not "then".

Comment: Note that daylight savings will not be taken into account when substracting dates like that, so in some cases your code will produce wrong results still (I mean with TotalHours).

Answer (score 1):

you want the `TotalHours` property rather than `Hours`:

```
 bool lessThen24Hours = (spaceEvent.EventDateTime - DateTime.Now).TotalHours < 24;
```

Comment: Can remove the redundant ternary.

Comment: @JonathonChase Rush of blood to the head trying to be first to answer. I've given myself a good talking to now. :-) Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

Try `(spaceEvent.EventDateTime - DateTime.Now).TotalHours`.
It gives you all the hours distance between two dates

Answer (score 1):

Use .TotalHours

`(spaceEvent.EventDateTime - DateTime.Now).TotalHours < 24`

put that inside Math.Abs() if you want the proximity of 24 hour regardless which time is first

Use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime so that time zones don't mess up your math.